Connection string works in VS but in IIS getting exception : "The ConnectionString property has not been initialized."
I am using ASP.NET Web API to read data from SQL Server. After publishing the API to IIS, I get this error:

The connection string property has not been initialized

C# code used to read connection string:
string sqlDataSource = _configuration.GetConnectionString("Test_Server");

Configured the connection strings in IIS 10.0, and here is my web.config file:
<connectionStrings>
    <remove name="LocalSqlServer" />
    <add name="Test_Server"
         connectionString="Server=ServerName;Database=DBName;User ID=myname;Password=mypassword"  />
</connectionStrings>


Wow - ISS - you're running your code on the International Space Station ? ;-)

Do you have a web.release.config file?

No, only web.config file is generated. @ThomasArdal

Does your project work fine locally? Does this error only occur on iis? This error is usually an incorrect connectionString, so please check your connectionString.

this error occurred due to the missing file "appSettings.json".
